# Search Preview (Thumbnail Previews) for SharePoint 2013

Tags: search, search-results, sharepoint-search

Our Search Preview/Thumbnail is displaying at the bottom of the screen when hovering over a document, rather than right next to the document.  Should we select a document further down the search results, the preview doesn't appear at all on the screen (unless we scroll down - and then we run the risk of losing the link on top).

Any ideas on how to get the preview to display next to the item selected?

[image: Search Preview/Thumbnail Displaying at bottom of screen]

Comment: Check you Firebug/IE Developer tool's console, see if there's any error that's causing it. While you're at it check the css of '.ms-srch-hover-outerContainer' if it's being overriden by other css.

Comment: It would also be helpful to include the browsers/versions you have tested as well. Is it happening with all users or just a few> Things like that.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be happening for all result types, so I suspect that you are causing it with a custom master page or CSS file. The hover is a hidden div on most Display Templates in:

```
<div id="_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-outerContainer"></div>
```

I would debug it by removing the customization and see that normal function returns. Then look for the offending code.

Another possibility is that you are interfering with the `currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback` code that determines where the hover div should be placed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to use a process of elimination to try to pinpoint what is causing the problem. It might have something to do with customisations to master page, page layout, css style sheets, display templates etc. Start with an out of the box version of a search center, verify that it behaves correctly, and one by one introduce your customisations to see where things fall over.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to fix the issue by removing the "Search Results" webpart.  We had added both the "Search" webpart and "Search Results" webpart to a "home" page (or team site).

On other search sites, we did not have the same problem so we dismissed the idea of it being the Master Page customization.

When we removed the webpart and forced the user to SharePoint's search result page, the web preview appeared correctly.

Thank you for your help!